# Why is my nested function undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function, undefined

This is the class of java scripts. I get the error of undefined for GetL()
and its code doesn't run (I tried random consoles inside and they never get run). The first part of the function shows the array but GetL shows undefined.

What am  I doing wrong?

```js
function getC() {
    var url = config.api.server + config.api.uri + "/c";
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(r) {
      if (!r.length) {
        console.warn("Empty");
      }
      config.c = r;
      console.log(r);
      $.map(config.c, function(item) {

        $("#c").append($('<option>').text(item.ci));

      });

      var a = $("#c").find("option:selected").text();


      function GetL() {

        var url = config.api.server + config.api.uri + "/l";

        $.getJSON(url).done(function(answer) {

          if (!answer.length) {
            console.warn("Empty list");
          }
          config.l = answer;
          console.log(answer);

          r.forEach(function(cName) {
            if (a == cName.ci) //check if name is equal to selection 
            {
              var x = cName.ci.l; //get the ls of that name and put it in a place holder 
              console.log(x); //undefined
              $.map(x, function(item) { //make a map to append those specific ls

                $("#l").append($('<option>').text(item.str));
              });
            }

          });

        }).fail(function(data, status, error) {
          console.error("Something went wrong");
        });

      }

      GetL();
    }).fail(function(data, status, error) {
      console.error("Something went wrong");
    });


  } //end big function
```

Comment: Eyeballing that, I can't see any reason why `GetL` would be undefined. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: `GetL` does not return anything to begin with. Furthermore, `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. I'm not totally sure what your expectation is.

Comment: By "the array" to you mean `a` or something else? (A shorter re-create that removes everything not needed to show the issue would make answering easier.)

Comment: Could you `console.log` the array `r` at the begining of your `GetL` function, and the item `cName` next `var x = cName.ci.l;` ?

Comment: Could you please include the *exact* error message in your question?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError : GetL is undefined - the exact error message

Comment: The function cannot return anything because its ajax call, but its updating a list. GetL updates the list by making a reference connection from getc parameters.

Comment: @soywood I can console all of them and they all return the desired answer but when i console(x) it shows me undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning the values that you are looking for.

`return x`

you can do

```
console.log(x)
return x
```

just to make sure the values match.